# Xcode 6 crashing when using Objective-C subproject inside Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a fairly large Obj-C library that's a subproject in Xcode in several Obj-C projects and it works well.

I'm trying to use that same library in a Swift project but it's crashing Xcode when it gets to a variable declaration of one of the types from my library.

The headers seem to be working because auto-complete sees the proper types from my library. I've added my library (libMylib.a) in Link Binary with Libraries just like in my other Obj-C projects.

```
class thing {
    var width: CGFloat
    // more variables
    var foo: MyClass    // this is a class contained in my subproject

   // functions, etc..

}
```

It crashes Xcode if the var foo line is there, not even when I create or access it. If it's just there. That's why I think it has something to do with not linking the subproject properly or similar.

Not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: Why the vote down? It's a legitimate question.

Comment: You might get better responses if you provide more information about the observed behavior than "it's crashing".  Source-code is often a great way to explain an issue in a way that can help others to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not like showing a few lines of code will show the problem. And it's not a "my app is crashing and I don't know why" kind of thing. I can't even debug it, it literally takes down Xcode.

Comment: I see. I missed that it's actually crashing Xcode itself.

Comment: I added a little more explanation. It's a difficult thing to visualize.