# Using an Obj-C sub-project in a Swift application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

My team has a few full Obj-C libraries we like te reuse in our projects. To do so, we usually set up a git submodule, and then add it to the xcode project as a sub-project (Using `target dependency`, `link binary with library` and updating the `User Header Search Paths`)

So far it's only been done in full Obj-C projects, and I'm now trying to use it in a Swift project but with very little success so far. I tried to add the `briding-header` file, referenced it in the project and filled it like so :

```
#import "MyLibraryHeader.h"
```

With the target header being in the `User Header Search Paths`.

It lets me build, but when using it in my Swift files:

```
    let test = MyLib();
    let secondTest = MyLib.classMethod1("some_arguments");
```

I get an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` on `secondTest`, and the following logs in the debugger:

```
(lldb) po test
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'test'

(lldb) po secondTest
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'MyProject' from AST context:
/Users/siegele/Sources/MyProject_iOS/MyProject/Classes/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h:12:9: error: 'MyLibraryHeader.h' file not found
#import "MyLibraryHeader.h"
        ^
failed to import bridging header '/Users/siegele/Sources/MyProject_iOS/MyProject/Classes/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h'
```

Found the following question with no answer : [Xcode 6 crashing when using Objective-C subproject inside Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374206/xcode-6-crashing-when-using-objective-c-subproject-inside-swift)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the `MyProject-Bridging-Header.h` filename matches the bridging header filename in hour plist file?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't build if Xcode can't find the file referenced in the Build Settings. You say plist but it's not where I should add it, is it ?

Comment: A minor work-around that has worked for me in XCode 6.1.1 is to type:
po print(test)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I followed the HockeyApp tutorial that can be found here: 
http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x/integrate-hockeyapp-for-ios-as-a-subproject

In the end, I was on the right tracks but messed up the Header Search Paths:

1. Add subproject xcodeproj to the workspace
2. On the main project : `Link binary with library`, and add the subproject product library (Bonus points : add it as a target dependency too)
3. Update `Header Search Paths` (**not** `User Header Search Paths`) accordingly
4. Import your `Library.h` in the main project `Bridging-Header.h` file

Answer (score 0):

What threw me off for a while is that the Swift Compiler setting for the Objective-C Bridging Header was not set automatically. Check the Build Settings for your target and ensure the "Objective-C Bridging Header" setting is not blank.